# Why didn't Seaplane explode when stung by a mosquito?

Tags: plot-explanation, jumanji-welcome-to-the-jungle

Earlier in *Jumanji: Welcome to the Jungle* we see the dialogue:

> Alex. What's up with all these candles?
>
> Uh Citronella, one of my weaknesses is mosquitoes.

If Seaplane has a weakness to mosquitoes and is stung by one, why doesn't he immediately explode like other characters exposed to their weaknesses?

Comment: Do we know that he has been stung by one?

Comment: @RoijanEskor Yes, it's why Jack Black (don't remember character's name) has to give him one of *her* lives

Comment: According to the linked question, Ruby implodes (not explodes) when she is poisoned. (I don't recall personally).

Comment: @stannius I'm not really focusing on the distinction between imploding and exploding, but instead on the "instantly dies without a chance" part

Comment: Don't have sources for this, but to me it seemed like Ruby exploding(imploding) was due to the lethality of her weakness, whereas the mosquitoes for Seaplane were an illness kill, which could take longer.

Comment: Wouldn't a game where everyone dies, under every circumstance, in exactly the same manner be considered a really crappy and unimaginative game?

Comment: No, not at all.  I'd have to disagree with that.  What games have you been playing?  It might be consistent in "if you take a number of bullets, you'll bleed out, every time," but not "you'll die the same way if you get shot, if you get blown up by a grenade, if you get hacked by a machete, if you get doused by a flame-thrower."  Dead is dead. Players know to expect their player to die if they lose.  The variety of manners of death tends to be pretty broad, for more popular games.

Comment: I agree with @PoloHoleSet. It's not necessary that every character of the game _(here, Jumanji)_ need to explode when they die. Kevin Hart's character exploded more because to give it a comic effect. Similarly, had Ruby exploded when stung by the Cobra, forget the scene being comedy, it would've looked wierd to some too; considering the seriousness of the scene.

Comment: No, there was no Jumanji video game, originally. It was a board game, and then, in the new movie, because it was magical, it transformed itself to be more appealing by turning into a video game cartridge in 1996.  The difference between technology in 1996 and the 80s is very vast, and, since it's magical and can suck human beings into the game, a feature definitely more advanced than 80s, 90s, 2000s, or present day games, there's no reason, at all, to imagine it would be constrained or unable to update its appeal. Anyway - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_p_H6h0_kt8 (Street Fighter death vid)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assumed that this was because he was about to die. I mean, really die. It's the only instance of a player character losing their last life in the movie so in universe it made sense to me that it would be a different effect.

Sadly I could not find any sources confirming this.

Comment: That's actually a great idea, I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Given all the game theory in Jumanji this makes sense, there are plenty of games where the last life behaves differently.

Comment: That's a good idea. There's a lot about the death mechanic that is either inconsistent or not explained, so that's as good a guess as any.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those things that seems like it happened that way just because if it didn't the next plot point (Brittany/Sheldon giving a life) wouldn't have been able to happen. If Seaplane just exploded, then there's no body to revive. His body had to be present because it drives Brittany's motivation to save him. He's attractive, so if his body goes away, Brittany doesn't care anymore and there's nothing she can do to save him.